# dotnet restore not updating to new version when using * placeholder in package reference

Tags: .net-core, nuget

**Background**

- .NET Core CLI (e.g., `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build`)
- SDK-style project files (e.g., `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`)
- An application project that depends on a package that I publish through a nuget server.
- Semantic versioning of my packages (e.g., `1.6.10`, is version `1.6.9`, with backwards compatible fixes)
- Project package references in the application with a patch placeholder (e.g., `1.6.*`)
- nuget.config file (with path to packages folder and list of NuGet sources.)

My project file for my application might contain this:

```
<PackageReference Include="MyDataAccessLibrary" Version="1.6.*" />
```

**Here is the problem:** When I publish a new version of my package to the nuget server, running `dotnet restore` on my development machine is not downloading that new version (if I have already been building against a previous version.)

For example, if I have been building against package version 1.6.9, I expected that `dotnet restore` would detect the recently published 1.6.10, install it, and use it when building my dependent application. That has not been my experience on my development machine. (On the build server, it works fine because it gets a clean copy for every build.)

Here is what I have been doing as a workaround on my dev machine:

- Edit the project file, replacing `1.6.*` with `1.6.10`.
- Run `dotnet restore`
- Watch the new package version be downloaded
- Edit the project file, reverting the `1.6.10` back to `1.6.*`

**Question:** What is the right way to say, "please download the latest patch for a package" in the above situation?

Comment: I'm not using a packages.config file. Consequently, `nuget update` gives me an error.

Answer (score 9):

I *think* I found the answer... the `--no-cache` option on dotnet restore.

```
dotnet restore --no-cache
```

Comment: I have the same problem. However `noCache` is explained like `Prevents NuGet from using packages from local machine caches.` Does it mean that package will be downloaded each time build starts ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was just using the NuGet Restore in the build pipeline and packages did not restore with latest version as I set in .csproj like version="1.0.*"

```yaml
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2   displayName: 'NuGet restore'   
        inputs:
        restoreSolution: Mobile.sln
        vstsFeed: '0120c3c...'
        noCache: true
```

After including dotnet restore command and moving dotnet clean on to top of pipeline,
my issue is fixed and I manage to restore with latest package version.

```yaml
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2   displayName: 'dotnet clean'   
        inputs:
        command: custom
        custom: clean

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2   displayName: 'dotnet restore'   
        inputs:
        command: restore
        vstsFeed: '0123a2z1...'
```